# How to display icons in actionbar and how to handle click events

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Trying to add actionar icons to actionbar and i'm using support library here is link i'm following [developerspage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

and here is my code to implement it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == R.id.toggle) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

and menu.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="menutoggle"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml, you can include this in each item you want to be clickable:

```
android:onClick="aRandomMethod"
```

Then in your activity, you must implement a method that supports the click, in this case, a method called aRandomMethod, like this:

```
public void aRandomMethod(MenuItem item){
        /// stuff to do when you click in the button
}
```

If you want your icon to be always displayed in the action bar, add:

```
 android:showAsAction="always"
```

The `onOptionsItemSelected` method that you have in your code is when you have the settings icon (three small dots) and then a submenu in the icon; is to handle the submenu.